# Is it necessary to add arm64-v8a in build.gradle file when using NDK libraries

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am using `NDK libraries` in my app, these are the settings in my gradle file.

```
  defaultConfig {

        applicationId 'com.aa.aa'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','x86'
        }
    }
```

But now if i upload my apk on play store, it give me error message that, my app is cont complaint with `64-bit architecture`.

Now if i add `arm64-v8a`, i am able to upload the build on playstore.

```
  defaultConfig {

        applicationId 'com.aa.aa'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        }
    }
```

My questions is that is that is it necessary to add `arm64-v8a` in build.gradle file when using NDK libraries.

Comment: If you plan on including armeabi-v7a, then yes, you must also support arm64-v8a. Note that there are very few devices that use x86 or x86_64 (the only recent ones that come to mind are Chromebooks).

Comment: Just remove the ndk-abiFilters part and the default configuration will generate the 4 libraries required by Play Store

Answer (score 1):

If taken literally, your question can be answered "No". If you remove the whole `abiFilters` line from build.gradle, your app will be built for 64-bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

To have native 64-bit compatibility is a Play Store requirement, and for app updates it is being enforced since August 2019. If you use other mechanisms to deliver your app, arm64-v8a is not necessary.